# faster ALTER COLUMN

Tags: performance, postgresql-12

Is there a method to do an ALTER COLUMN in postgres 12 on an huge table without waiting a lifetime?

I try to convert a field from bigint to smallint :

```
ALTER TABLE huge ALTER COLUMN result_code TYPE SMALLINT;
```

It takes 8 hours, is there a smarter method? The table has sequences, keys and foreign keys

Comment: That change requires the entire table to re-written. But I doubt you will get any substantial size improvement (=reduction) with that anyway.

Comment: I think you can create new table with updated `COLUMN` and copy data, this might be a faster way.

Comment: Are you trying to save space?

Comment: I found a 10-15 % reduction in database size , because the bigint fields where so many  and I modified them all in int or smallint

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328) - already asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62797936/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Laurenz Albe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464308/laurenz-albe) answered this question on a similar post

this is the answer:

> The table has to be rewritten, and you have to wait.
> If you have several columns whose data type you want to change, you can use several ALTER COLUMN clauses in a single ALTER TABLE
> statement and save time that way.

> An alternative idea would be to use logical replication: set up an empty copy of the database (pg_dump -s), where your large table is
> defined with smallint columns. Replicate your database to that
> database, and switch over as soon as replication has caught up.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62797936/is-there-a-method-to-do-an-alter-column-in-postgres-12-on-an-huge-table-without/62815751#62815751) is the question

Comment: Please edit your post and add the URL to the post where Laurenz said that.

Comment: @MichaelKutz: Gabriele cross posted this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62797936/